# Is there any way to play vorbis ogg files in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, xamarin.ios, ogg, vorbis

Is there any supportive/Binding library Or any tool available to run .ogg files into Xamarin.ios project ?

I already tried with

1. Nvorbis, NAudio: those library needs lots of system dlls which is not good to use for mobile application development.
2. IDZAQAudioPlayer: but its a Xcode project ( working fine with Xcode but i need something for Xamarin.iOS - Xamarin Studio)
3. Urho.Audio: It does not support IOS 7.0

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: NVorbis only requires the basic .Net framework (which Xamarin.IOS should support directly).  Have you tried using a different audio library with NVorbis?